# Certificate Validation on Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've found that if you connect to a Cloud SQL instance over SSL the CommonName provided in the server's certificate is `my-project-123456:myinstance` which renders the certificate un-validatable, as the client expects that the CN to be either the hostname or IP.

Every solution to this problem seems to amount to "just disable validation", which is not acceptable to me because:

1. Why has GCP decided to do everything *else* correctly, providing a CA cert and client certificates, only to drop the ball on identity validation? By disabling validation you're basically saying "I'm OK with being MITMed at some point".
2. What about projects where we can't play fast and loose with validation because of PIPA/HIPAA?
3. What about mySQL clients that don't support turning validation off? eg: All PHP 5.6 mysql libs using mysqlnd prior to the upcoming 5.6.16 release.

Is there any way to make SSL work correctly on Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for not having the IP address of the instance in the common name of the server certificate is because these IPs can change. What is the IP address of instance A today can be the IP address of instance B tomorrow, because A was deleted, or A decided that it doesn't want the IP address anymore. So, the instance name was decided as being a more unique identification of the instance.

Also, the mysql client libraries by default have hostname verification disabled. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ssl-options.html

With regards to MITM attacks, it is not possible to MITM attack a Cloud SQL instance because the server certificate and the each of the client certificates are signed by unique self-signed CAs which are never used to sign more than one cert. The server only ever trusts certificates signed by one of these CAs. The reason for using unique CAs per client cert was because MySQL 5.5 did not support certificate revocation lists, and we also did not want to deal CRLs, but wanted to support deletion of client certs.

We will look into ways of supporting SSL for clients which cannot turn off  hostname validation. But I cannot promise an ETA on this.

Cloud SQL Team.

Comment: 1. It's not the instance name, it's the project and instance name joined by a colon. If it were *only* the instance name, or the joiner were a hostname-permissable character I could work around this in DNS or hosts file. 2. Because of #1 everyone *must disable cert validation* so if someone MITMs the connection and fouls up the certificate its not like anyone is going to be notified. 3. The mySQL official libraries may have vaildation off by default, but that neither makes it correct nor advisable to run like that, and 3rd-party client libraries [eg: PHP's mysqlnd] may choose *secure* defaults

Comment: Any update on "We will look into ways of supporting SSL for clients which cannot turn off hostname validation" @Easwar? I know no ETA, but it's been 8 years now... Just having the same issue with using CloudSQL, enforced SSL and a client, which enforces hostname validation. AuthProxy not working.